# How do you resolve circular imports in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, design-patterns, circular-dependency

I'm new to programming in Kotlin and I've already managed to run into the classic circular dependency issue - I know Kotlin can cope with those but I'd like to know how would I go about changing my design to avoid it. What structures or Kotlin functionality should I use in the following?

```
import MyClass

interface MyInterface {
    fun useMyClass(myInstance: MyClass)
}
```

```
import MyInterface

class MyClass(myList: List<MyInterface>) {
    val storedList: List<MyInterface> = myList
    var myValue: Int = 10
}
```

I would like `MyClass` to store multiple objects which implement `MyInterface`, but I would also like each of those objects to reference the class they have been passed to, i.e. each call of `useMyClass` would have the signature of `useMyClass(this)`.

For example, I could create a class

```
class ImplementingMyInterfaceClass(): MyInterface {
    override fun useMyClass(myInstance: MyClass) {
         myInstance.myValue += 10
    }
}
```

and call it somewhere within `MyClass`:

```
ImplementingMyInterfaceClass().useMyClass(this)
```

Technically I could create another construct in the middle which would be used by `MyInterface` and inherited/implemented by `MyClass`, but this just doesn't feel correct. Any suggestions?

Note: In my specific issue, it might be helpful to consider each implementation of `MyInterface` as a sort of a "modifier" (since it will modify the instance of the class) - `MyClass` instances should be aware of its modifiers and each modifier should be able to modify that instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to largely depend on what the interface has to do, but you could limit its function argument to some interface that MyClass implements:

```
interface MyInterface {
    fun increaseSomeValue(someValueHolder: MySubInterface)

    interface MySubInterface {
        var myValue: Int
    }
}

class MyClass(myList: List<MyInterface>): MyInterface.MySubInterface {
    val storedList: List<myInterface> = myList
    override var myValue: Int = 10
}
```

Or your interface can take a property argument:

```
interface MyInterface {
    fun increaseSomeValue(someValue: KMutableProperty<Int>)
}

class MyInterfaceImpl: MyInterface {
    override fun increaseSomeValue(someValue: KMutableProperty<Int>) {
        someValue.setter.call(someValue.getter.call() + 10)
    }
}

// from MyClass:
storedList.first().printSomeValue(::myValue)
```

In other cases where we don't need to both get and set, it could be cleaner to take a more versatile function argument (lambdas could be passed):

```
interface MyInterface {
    fun printSomeValue(valueProvider: () -> Int)
}

class MyInterfaceImpl: MyInterface {
    override fun printSomeValue(valueProvider: () -> Int) {
        println(valueProvider())
    }
}

// from MyClass:
storedList.first().printSomeValue(::myValue)
// or
storedList.first().printSomeValue { 1..10.random() }
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer :) I love the solutions but unfortunately, in my case, the interface has to access a class instance by itself rather than the fields within it. If you consider each implementation of the interface as a sort of a "modifier" (since it will modify the instance of the class) - `myClass` instances should be aware of its modifiers and each modifier should be able to modify that instance. I am still digesting your answer and need to read up on some syntax you've shared here but at first glance, it is not covering my specific issue.

Comment: I will accept your answer if no alternatives come with time, however, as it provides good general guidance towards the problem - hope you don't mind waiting a little bit!